# Excel Office Script not clearing cells. Getting unreachable code detected (7027) error

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have this script which works all except for the clearing of the B4:B120 area "// Clear the "Margin Updates" column." section which is greyed out for some reason):

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): ReportImages {
  // Recalculate the workbook to ensure all tables and charts are updated.
  workbook.getApplication().calculate(ExcelScript.CalculationType.full);

  // Get the data from the "Target Margins - FHM" table. (name of Excel tab, not name of table)
  let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  const table = workbook.getWorksheet('Target Margins - FHM').getTables()[0];
  const rows = table.getRange().getTexts();

  // Get only the Product Type and "Margin Update" columns, then remove the "Total" row.
  const selectColumns = rows.map((row) => {
    return [row[0], row[1]];
  });

  // Delete the "ChartSheet" worksheet if it's present, then recreate it.
  workbook.getWorksheet('ChartSheet')?.delete();
  const chartSheet = workbook.addWorksheet('ChartSheet');

  // Add the selected data to the new worksheet.
  const targetRange = chartSheet.getRange('A1').getResizedRange(selectColumns.length - 1, selectColumns[0].length - 1);
  targetRange.setValues(selectColumns);

   // Get images of the chart and table, then return them for a Power Automate flow.
  const tableImage = table.getRange().getImage();
  return { tableImage };

  // Clear the "Margin Updates" column.
  const targetSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  const getRange = targetSheet.getRange("B4:B120");
  getRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);`

}

// The interface for table and chart images.
interface ReportImages {
  tableImage: string
}
```

The code copies the data in sections of the A and B columns (which constitute a table) and sends an email via Power Automate flow. Unfortunately, I need the section of the B column to be clear of values (not formatting or style) after which this flow is not doing.

I'd greatly appreciate help with this problem.

Thank you.

@cybernetic. nomad:
When I try using `Range ("B4:B120").Clear` I receive

> unreachable code detected (7027)

and

> and "cannot find name 'Range' (2304)

[Office Script Range Clear Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH3wS.png)

Comment: `Range("B4:B120").Clear`?

Comment: It appears the section is greyed out because of the backticks at the beginning and at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the function exits as soon as the `return` keyword is evaluated. That's why it's saying your code is unreachable. So you have to restructure your code so that the return happens at the end. So you can update your code to look something like this:

```js
    // Clear the "Margin Updates" column.
    const targetSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const getRange = targetSheet.getRange("B4:B120");
    getRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    
    return { tableImage };
```